# How to connect to a new database using PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

So I've been trying to learn how to use MySQL with PHP, and I've managed to create a connection and create a database along with a table. What I don't know how to do is create the database along with the tables all in one go.

What I mean by this is easier shown in my code (Which will show unable to connect error message because the connect method is trying to connect to a database that does not exist.

```
    <?php
    $servername = isset($_POST["servername"]) ? $_POST["servername"] : '';
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $dbname = $_POST["dbname"];

    // Create connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    // Create database
    $sql = "CREATE DATABASE myDB";
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "Database created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error creating database: " . $conn->error;
    }

    // sql to create table
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE MyGuests (
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(50),
    reg_date TIMESTAMP
    )";

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo "Table MyGuests created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error creating table: " . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
    ?>
```

So, all I am trying to achieve is Connect to MySQL, create the database, create a table for said database and close the connection all within one .php file.

On a side note, due to the user being able to define a database name (`$dbname`), how would I add this value into the MySQL code above? I heard somewhere that you're supposed to add the variable into quotes? So `'$dbname'`. Any help with that would be good too! Thanks in advance!

Okay, the reason for this question is because I am creating a setup-type page where the user will be able to connect to their own database, allowing them to give it a name and connect using their credentials. Obviously I am not very experienced within this field, I hope I have explained it better.

Comment: no, you don't just blindly put quotes on everything. you need to produce VALID sql. `create table '$foo'` won't work, because `'foo'` is a string literal, and won't be interpreted as a table name. it has to be `create table foo`.

Comment: You have to select one db which is present in the database. After that you can create a new database

Comment: you're open to a serious SQL injection if this is used on a live site, using unsanitized POST arrays.

Comment: @MarcB where did you put that "enjoy... p3wned" thingy of yours again? ^

Comment: Please, please, please don't use this code on a production site.  Is there any reason these functions need to be handled in your code rather than in a separate package like PhpMyAdmin?  Why are you creating code that can create whole new databases on the whim of your users?  This is just begging for problems.

Comment: @Jason The code will be available for download as part of a new project, it will simply be put in an install directory, after the user installs the site, the install directory will be deleted, thus deleting the creation of database code :)

Comment: Also, please consider using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) object instead of mysqli_* functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the code you have looks fine to me. The only thing I think your missing is after you create a database you have to call

```
$conn->select_db("myDB");
```

Also if you want to have the database name be $dbname then

```
$sql = "CREATE DATABASE myDB";
```

should be

```
$sql = "CREATE DATABASE " . $dbname;
```

If I didn't cover your problem please give me more detail on your problem.

Comment: Ah thank you! I thought it would have been something simple with the adding of variables! As for the database selecting, that was exactly the code I needed! Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

where you passing all of this variable ?

$servername = isset($_POST["servername"]) ? $_POST["servername"] : ''; 
$username = $_POST["username"]; 
$password = $_POST["password"]; 
$dbname = $_POST["dbname"];

just simply hardcode the servername, username, password and your dbname.

Comment: Simply hardcoding them would defect the purpose of allowing the user to connect to their own database. That's what this code is supposed to do, allow the user to enter their own credentials to connect and name their databases. :)